# A peculiar linear programming: random variables and limits

Tags: limits, random-variables, expectation, linear-programming, law-of-large-numbers

I want to ask your point of view on the following problem I am struggling with. Your opinion would be extremely helpful to help me understand how to approach the exercise.

Consider the following linear programming 
$$
\max_{a_{ij} \text{ }\forall i=1,...,I \text{ }\forall j=1,...,J}\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}a_{ij}\epsilon_{ij}
$$
$$
\text{s.t. } \\
(1) \text{ }a_{ij}\in \{0,1\} \text{ }\forall i=1,...,I \text{  and } \forall j=1,...,J\\
(2) \text{ }\sum_{j=1}^{J}a_{ij}\leq 1\text{ $\forall i=1,...,I$}\\ (3)\text{ }\sum_{i=1}^{I}a_{ij}\leq 1\text{ $\forall j=1,...,J$}\\
(4) \text{ }\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}a_{ij}=b\leq \min\{I,J\}
$$

My ultimate objective is to derive the closed form for the the maximum value of the objective function.

The peculiarities of this problem are:

**(1)** $\{\epsilon_{ij}\}_{i,j}$ are i.i.d. continuous random variables with distribution $F$

**(2)** I want to study the limiting behaviour of the maximum value of the objective function as $I\rightarrow \infty$ and $J\rightarrow \infty$.

---

First scenario: the problem does not make sense; in this case, I want to dig deeply and ask your help to find its main issues as at the moment I'm totally blind.

Second scenario: the problem does not contains logical flaws; in this case, my intuition is that in the limit the objective function should become a rescaled expectation by some law of large numbers. Do you have any specific thought that could enlighten me or papers/notes/books in the literature that may related?

Comment: This is a form of stochastic optimization, and the standard techniques for solving linear programs (e.g. simplex method) are not applicable.

Comment: Thank you. A good reference? Does stochastic optimization cover also the case with limits?

Comment: This is not a linear program due to the integer constraints.  It is a matching problem: You have a matrix of $\epsilon_{ij}$ values and you pick exactly $b$ of them such that you can pick at most one per row and one per column.  If the random variables are iid and take values over $[0,c]$, and for all $\epsilon>0$ we have $P[\epsilon_{ij} \in [c-\epsilon, c]]>0$, and either $I$ or $J$ goes to $\infty$, then with high probability we can find multiple entries close to $c$ on every row (or column, whichever is going to infinity).  So  $Val \rightarrow bc$ wp1, and $E[Val]\rightarrow bc$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer gives details on my comment. Assume $b, I, J$ are positive integers with $I \geq b, J \geq b$, and WLOG assume $I$ is growing to infinity. 
Define 
$$ c = \sup \{x \in \mathbb{R} : P[\epsilon_{11}>x]>0\} $$
Define $Val_I^{opt}$ as the optimal (max-weight) value of the matching problem, as a function of $I$.

#### Case 1:  Suppose $c\leq 0$.

In this trivial case we have $Val_I^{opt}=0$ with prob 1, since, with prob 1,  all $\epsilon_{ij}$ entries are less than or equal to zero and the best thing to do is to choose nothing.

#### Case 2: Suppose $c=\infty$.

In this case we have
$$ Val_I^{opt} \geq \max_{i \in \{1, ..., I\}, j\in \{1, ..., J\}}\{\epsilon_{ij}\} \overset{I}{\rightarrow} \infty \quad (wp1)$$
and so of course $\lim_{I\rightarrow\infty}E[Val_I^{opt}]=\infty$.

#### Case 3: Suppose $0<c<\infty$.

In this case it can be shown that 
\begin{align}
&Val_I^{opt} \rightarrow cb \quad (wp1) \\
&\lim_{I\rightarrow\infty} E[Val_I^{opt}] = cb
\end{align}

This is because $Val_I^{opt} \geq Val_I^{greedy}$ where $Val_I^{greedy}$ is the value achieved by the following greedy matching strategy:

- Step 1: Choose the largest entry in the first column.
- Step 2: Choose the largest entry in the second column, considering only the $I-1$ rows not yet chosen.
- Step 3: Choose the largest entry in the third column, considering only the $I-2$ rows not yet chosen.
- and so on...
- Step $b$: Choose the largest entry in the $b$th column, considering only the $I-(b-1)$ rows not yet chosen.

and it is easy to compute $E[Val_I^{greedy}]$ and $\lim_{I\rightarrow\infty} P[Val_I^{greedy} > b(c-\delta)]$ for all $\delta>0$.

Comment: Thank you. Extremely enlightening. I have some questions if you have time. $Val^{opt}_I$ is a random variable, because of $\epsilon$, correct? Case 1: you have shown that $Val^{opt}_I$ is a degenerate random variable equal to constant $0$. Case 2: you have shown that $Val^{opt}_I$ converges almost surely to $\infty$. Correct? I was wondering whether this is somehow related to extreme value theory, i.e., with a rescaling we might ensure that $\max_{i=1,...,I, j=1,...,J}\{\epsilon_{ij}\}$ is non degenerate. But then the problem would completely change?

Comment: Case 3: could we do this with both $I$ and $J$ going to infinity? I have not understood what we have to show: (1) we have a random variable $Val^{greedy}_{I,J}$ designed according to the greedy algorithm described above; (2) we want to show that for $I$ and $J$ fixed the expected value of $Val^{greedy}_{I,J}$ is "blah"; (3) we move $I$ and $J$ to infinity and we want to show that $Val^{greedy}_{I,J}$ converges in probability "blah"; (4) we make some conclusions on $Val^{opt}_{I,J}$ (how?)

Comment: Also, is case 3 based on assuming $b<\infty$? Thank you for your help

Comment: One more question: in the greedy algorithm you pick always one element per row. Is that because the constraints $\leq 1$ are binding?

Comment: And: aren't my constraints redundant? I mean the constraints above aren't equivalent to $$
(1) \text{ }a_{ij}\in \{0,1\} \text{ }\forall i=1,...,I \text{  and } \forall j=1,...,J\\
(2) \text{ }\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{J}a_{ij}=b\leq \min\{I,J\}
$$

Comment: On your second and third comments: $Val_{I,J}\geq Val_{I,b}$ always (assuming $J\geq b$), and the same limiting behavior holds.  And indeed we assume $b$ is fixed, i.e., is not of the form $b_I$.

Comment: On your last two comments, using the equation numbers labeled in your question:  Constraint (2) says we pick at most one entry on each row $i$; Constraint (3) says we pick at most one entry on each column $j$; Constraint (4) says we pick at most $b$ entries in total.   Constraints (1) and (4) alone allow us to pick $b$ entries all on the first row, which violates constraint (2). So (1) and (4) do not imply (2) and (3).

Comment: Removing constraints (2), (3) reduces the problem to choosing the $b$ largest entries of your $(\epsilon_{ij})$ matrix.  On the other hand, removing constraint (4) reduces the problem to a max-weight match in a weighted bipartite graph.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your answers. I am still confused on your last sentence for case 3 "It is easy to compute $E[Val^{greedy}_I]$ and $\lim_{I\rightarrow \infty} ...$". (a) What are these two values? Why we can conclude from there that $Val^{opt}_I\rightarrow_{a.s.}cb$?

Comment: For example, it is a basic probability computation to compute the probability that all entries chosen by the greedy algorithm are larger than $c-\delta$.